# Reading the registry and Wow6432Node key

Tags: c#, registry, 64-bit, wow64

I have some code that reads the registry and looks for a value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\App\` but when running on 64-bit versions of Windows the value is under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\App\`.

How should I best approach this? Do I need a 64-bit installer or should I rewrite my code to detect both places?

Comment: Which program manages the registry keys under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\App? Are you trying to read registry keys created by another program?

Comment: Hi, No it is my app that reads the key, the key is written in the registry by the Visual Studio 2008 installer.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you mark you C# program as x86 (and not Any CPU) then it will see `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\App` as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\App\`.

A .NET program for Any CPU will run as a 64-bit process if 64-bit .NET is installed. The 32-bit registry is under the `Wow6432Node` for 64-bit programs.

Comment: @Arve: I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but this trick does nothing for older WinXP machines - our company still uses hundreds of these and the Wow6432Node key is not on them.

Comment: The Wow6432Node key only exists on 64bit machines

Comment: Or if developers 'by mistake' hard code registry key paths with Wow6432Node in them. On my current machine I have this key as evidence: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Wow6432Node\Lenovo. 
32 bit code thinking its 64 bit but wants to write to 32 bit registry. Bad Lenovo :)

Answer (score 91):

On an x64 machine, here is an example of how to access the 32-bit view of the registry:

```
using (var view32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser,
                                            RegistryView.Registry32))
{
  using (var clsid32 = view32.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\CLSID\", false))
  {
    // actually accessing Wow6432Node 
  }
}
```

... as compared to...

```
using (var view64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser,
                                            RegistryView.Registry64))
{
  using (var clsid64 = view64.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\CLSID\", true))
  {
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice example. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/shared-registry-keys lists which keys are redirected and which are shared.

Comment: Sweet never even knew about the RegistryView. Worked great!

Answer (score 7):

+1 to Wally's answer, but his solution works for .NET 4.0 and higher.

I've found another solution, which also works for .NET 2.0 [here](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa/)

```
#region RegHelper
enum RegSAM
{
    QueryValue = 0x0001,
    SetValue = 0x0002,
    CreateSubKey = 0x0004,
    EnumerateSubKeys = 0x0008,
    Notify = 0x0010,
    CreateLink = 0x0020,
    WOW64_32Key = 0x0200,
    WOW64_64Key = 0x0100,
    WOW64_Res = 0x0300,
    Read = 0x00020019,
    Write = 0x00020006,
    Execute = 0x00020019,
    AllAccess = 0x000f003f
}

static class RegHive
{
    public static UIntPtr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = new UIntPtr(0x80000002u);
    public static UIntPtr HKEY_CURRENT_USER = new UIntPtr(0x80000001u);
}

static class RegistryWOW6432
{
    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
    static extern uint RegOpenKeyEx(UIntPtr hKey, string lpSubKey, uint ulOptions, int samDesired, out int phkResult);

    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
    static extern uint RegCloseKey(int hKey);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegQueryValueEx")]
    public static extern int RegQueryValueEx(int hKey, string lpValueName, int lpReserved, ref uint lpType, System.Text.StringBuilder lpData, ref uint lpcbData);

    static public string GetRegKey64(UIntPtr inHive, String inKeyName, string inPropertyName)
    {
        return GetRegKey64(inHive, inKeyName, RegSAM.WOW64_64Key, inPropertyName);
    }

    static public string GetRegKey32(UIntPtr inHive, String inKeyName, string inPropertyName)
    {
        return GetRegKey64(inHive, inKeyName, RegSAM.WOW64_32Key, inPropertyName);
    }

    static public string GetRegKey64(UIntPtr inHive, String inKeyName, RegSAM in32or64key, string inPropertyName)
    {
        //UIntPtr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = (UIntPtr)0x80000002;
        int hkey = 0;

        try
        {
            uint lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(RegHive.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, inKeyName, 0, (int)RegSAM.QueryValue | (int)in32or64key, out hkey);
            if (0 != lResult) return null;
            uint lpType = 0;
            uint lpcbData = 1024;
            StringBuilder AgeBuffer = new StringBuilder(1024);
            RegQueryValueEx(hkey, inPropertyName, 0, ref lpType, AgeBuffer, ref lpcbData);
            string Age = AgeBuffer.ToString();
            return Age;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (0 != hkey) RegCloseKey(hkey);
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

**Usage:**

```
string value64 = RegistryWOW6432.GetRegKey64(RegHive.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "RegisteredOrganization");
string value32 = RegistryWOW6432.GetRegKey32(RegHive.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "RegisteredOrganization");
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an all-in-one solution that would cover x32 / x64 systems and capture apps installed on local machine or user account.

```
    public class InstalledProgramInfo
    {
        public string name;
        public string path;
    }

        public static InstalledProgramInfo FindInstalledApp(string findname, bool dump = false)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(findname)) return null;

        string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

        RegistryHive[] keys = new RegistryHive[] { RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryHive.LocalMachine };
        RegistryView[] views = new RegistryView[] { RegistryView.Registry32, RegistryView.Registry64 };

        foreach (var hive in keys)
        {
            foreach (var view in views)
            {
                RegistryKey rk = null, 
                    basekey = null;

                try
                {
                    basekey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, view);
                    rk = basekey.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { continue; }

                if (basekey == null || rk == null) 
                    continue;

                if (rk == null)
                {
                    if (dump) Console.WriteLine("ERROR: failed to open subkey '{0}'", uninstallKey);
                    return null;
                }

                if (dump) Console.WriteLine("Reading registry at {0}", rk.ToString());

                foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName);
                        if (sk == null) continue;

                        object skname = sk.GetValue("DisplayName");

                        object skpath = sk.GetValue("InstallLocation");
                        if (skpath == null)
                        {
                            skpath = sk.GetValue("UninstallString");
                            if (skpath == null) continue;
                            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(skpath.ToString());
                            skpath = fi.Directory.FullName;
                        }

                        if (skname == null || skpath == null) continue;

                        string thisname = skname.ToString();
                        string thispath = skpath.ToString();

                        if (dump) Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", thisname, thispath);

                        if (!thisname.Equals(findname, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                            continue;

                        InstalledProgramInfo inf = new InstalledProgramInfo();
                        inf.name = thisname;
                        inf.path = thispath;

                        return inf;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // todo
                    }
                }                   
            } // view
        } // hive

        return null;
    }
```