# WIX checking for SQL Reporting Services is installed

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.5

Is there anyway of telling if SSRS is installed on a machine using WIX?  I can tell if SQL is installed but would also like to check for Reporting Services as well if possible.

Comment: I think [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179314.aspx) outlines the registry settings you can rely on checking for Reporting Services (bottom of the page).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23703749)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do some registry searching. I usually pull this logic into a custom action.

First open up this registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\Instance Names\RS

It contains a mapping between all the externally used instance names (e.g. MSSQLSERVER for the default instance) and the internal names SQL uses (default for 2008R2 is MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER)

Then you can use the internal name to lookup setup information about the instance. For the default RS instance in 2008R2 this would be:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Setup

Here you will find all the info you should need. Version, edition, path on disk, configuration status, etc.

**Note: If you are on a 64bit box you may also need to check for 32bit SQL installs under the Wow6432Node registry root**

[C# Reading the registry and Wow6432Node key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039186/c-reading-the-registry-and-wow6432node-key)