# How to retrieve list of applications from registry in Windows 64 bit

Tags: c#, registry

I have app which retrieve applications from registry. In 32bits Windows it works correctly. But part of the systems are 64bits, and my app read only applications which are 32 bits.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine;
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey subKey1 =
                regKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");

            string[] subKeyNames = subKey1.GetSubKeyNames();
            List<string> lst = new List<string>();
```

I don't have 64 bit Windows and I cannot check how registry looks on 64 bit machine.

Thanks

Comment: "I don't have 64 bit Windows and I cannot check how registry looks on 64 bit machine." --- you can install VMWare player or VirtualBox (both are free) and windows x64 (which has 30 days free trial) and see it yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of [registry redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Specifically, there is a `Wow6432Node` that contains registry keys for 32-bit processes on a 64-bit OS ([WOW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64)).

- See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.
- See also this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039186/c-sharp-reading-the-registry-and-wow6432node-key).