# What to pass as the first parameter to IActiveScriptProfilerControl.StartProfiling?

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop, iactivescript

Trying to use [`IActiveScriptProfilerControl::StartProfiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836473(v=vs.94).aspx) from my C# code, I've created this interface definition:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid(@"784b5ff0-69b0-47d1-a7dc-2518f4230e90")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IActiveScriptProfilerControl
{
    void StartProfiling(
        ref Guid clsidProfilerObject, 
        ProfilerEventMask eventMask, 
        uint dwContext);

    // ...
}
```

Which I believe is correctly translated to .NET.

The original first parameter is defined as

```
[in] REFCLSID clsidProfilerObject
```

With these definitions:

```
typedef GUID CLSID;
typedef CLSID *REFCLSID;
```

I'm also able to create an instance of Microsofts `JQueryScriptEngine` object and query for the `IActiveScriptProfilerControl`.

What I'm currently failing at is how to tell the `StartProfiling` function to use my `IActiveScriptProfilerCallback`-derived object.

**My question:**

How to connect my own profiler callback class with the active script profiler control interface through a call to `IActiveScriptProfilerControl::StartProfiling`?

Ideally, I would love to do this *without* the need to [RegAsm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx) my class.

**Update 1:**

I've changed the first parameter of interface definition to:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid(@"784b5ff0-69b0-47d1-a7dc-2518f4230e90")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IActiveScriptProfilerControl
{
    void StartProfiling(
        IActiveScriptProfilerCallback clsidProfilerObject, // <-- changed.
        ProfilerEventMask eventMask, 
        uint dwContext);

    // ...
}
```

and tried to call this function by passing an instance of my `IActiveScriptProfilerCallback`-derived class.

Still, I get the error:

> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Comment: I have no personal experience, but according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc843609(v=vs.94).aspx) you can't have a profiler created/invoked without registering it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Awesome! After a quick test, this seems to work. I'm now trying to see how to do it _without_ the need to call RegAsm on my DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Update from my future self that came here while searching for a similar error)

I've managed to solve this by [monitoring the registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), both when doing a [Regasm.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool) call on my assembly, as well as when monitoring what keys the profiler requests when valling `StartProfiling`.

These keys were required for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`:

> REGEDIT4
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback]
>   @="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback\CLSID]
>   @="{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}]
>   @="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}\InprocServer32]
>   @="mscoree.dll" "ThreadingModel"="Both"
>   "Class"="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback"
>   "Assembly"="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler,
>   Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
>   "RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319" "CodeBase"="file:///C:/P/Zeta
>   Producer/13/Zeta Producer
>   Main/Bin/Applications/ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.dll"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}\InprocServer32\14.1.0.0]
>   "Class"="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback"
>   "Assembly"="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler,
>   Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
>   "RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319" "CodeBase"="file:///C:/P/Zeta
>   Producer/13/Zeta Producer
>   Main/Bin/Applications/ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.dll"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}\ProgId]
>   @="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}\Implemented Categories{62C8FE65-4EBB-45E7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]

[Another suggestion](http://www.hexacorn.com/blog/2014/04/27/beyond-good-ol-run-key-part-11/) for JScript is to also add:

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]
>   "JS_PROFILER"="{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}"

Since I wanted my program to run without administrative privileges, I've create a class to create the above keys unter `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, wich also works.

Following is the full class file for reference purposes:

```
namespace ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.Helper
{
    using Microsoft.Win32;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Security.AccessControl;
    using System.Security.Principal;
    using Zeta.VoyagerLibrary.Common.IO;

    public static class ProfilerComRegistration
    {
        public const string ClsidString = @"1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914";
        public static readonly Guid Clsid = new Guid(ClsidString);

        /*
        REGEDIT4

        [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback]
        @="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback"

        [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback\CLSID]
        @="{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}"

        [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}]
        @="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback"

        [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}\InprocServer32]
        @="mscoree.dll"
        "ThreadingModel"="Both"
        "Class"="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback"
        "Assembly"="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
        "RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
        "CodeBase"="file:///C:/P/Zeta Producer/13/Zeta Producer Main/Bin/Applications/ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.dll"

        [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}\InprocServer32\15.0.0.0]
        "Class"="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback"
        "Assembly"="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
        "RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
        "CodeBase"="file:///C:/P/Zeta Producer/13/Zeta Producer Main/Bin/Applications/ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.dll"

        [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}\ProgId]
        @="ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback"

        [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45E7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]
        */

        /*
        Siehe http://www.hexacorn.com/blog/2014/04/27/beyond-good-ol-run-key-part-11/:

        [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]
        "JS_PROFILER"="{1C406FBA-59EF-4FB2-938C-C1DA182D5914}"
         */

        public static void Register()
        {
            // Achtung vor dem Wow6432Node-Schlüssel.
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039186/reading-the-registry-and-wow6432node-key
            var views = new[]
            {
                RegistryView.Registry32,
                RegistryView.Registry64
            };

            foreach (var registryView in views)
            {
                var key = checkCreateKey(
                    registryView,
                    @"Software\Classes\ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback");
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.SetValue(null,
                        @"ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback",
                        RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.Close();
                }

                key = checkCreateKey(
                    registryView,
                    @"Software\Classes\ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback\CLSID");
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.SetValue(null, $@"{{{ClsidString}}}", RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.Close();
                }

                key = checkCreateKey(
                    registryView,
                    $@"Software\Classes\CLSID\{{{ClsidString}}}");
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.SetValue(null,
                        @"ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback",
                        RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.Close();
                }

                key = checkCreateKey(
                    registryView,
                    $@"Software\Classes\CLSID\{{{ClsidString}}}\InprocServer32");
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.SetValue(null, @"mscoree.dll", RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.SetValue(@"ThreadingModel", @"Both", RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.SetValue(@"Class",
                        @"ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback",
                        RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.SetValue(@"Assembly",
                        @"ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
                        RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.SetValue(@"RuntimeVersion", @"v4.0.30319", RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.SetValue(@"CodeBase", getFileUrl(), RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.Close();
                }

                key = checkCreateKey(
                    registryView,
                    $@"Software\Classes\CLSID\{{{ClsidString}}}\InprocServer32\15.0.0.0");
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.SetValue(@"Class",
                        @"ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback",
                        RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.SetValue(@"Assembly",
                        @"ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
                        RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.SetValue(@"RuntimeVersion", @"v4.0.30319", RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.SetValue(@"CodeBase", getFileUrl(), RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.Close();
                }

                key = checkCreateKey(
                    registryView,
                    $@"Software\Classes\CLSID\{{{ClsidString}}}\ProgId");
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.SetValue(null,
                        @"ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback",
                        RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.Close();
                }

                // Aus der Dokumentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/cc843609(v=vs.94):
                //
                // The JavaScript language runtime checks the JS_PROFILER environment variable on creation
                // to determine whether profiling should be enabled. If this variable is set to the CLSID
                // of the profiler, the language runtime creates an instance of the profiler COM object,
                // using the value of the variable to determine which profiler to create.

                // Ein Beispiel habe ich hier gefunden:
                // http://www.hexacorn.com/blog/2014/04/27/beyond-good-ol-run-key-part-11/

                key = checkCreateKey(registryView, @"Environment");
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.SetValue(@"JS_PROFILER", $@"{{{ClsidString}}}", RegistryValueKind.String);
                    key.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private static string getFileUrl()
        {
            // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location),
                @"ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.dll");
            return PathHelper.ConvertFilePathToFileUrl(filePath);
        }

        public static void Unregister()
        {
            // Achtung vor dem Wow6432Node-Schlüssel.
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039186/reading-the-registry-and-wow6432node-key
            var views = new[]
            {
                RegistryView.Registry32,
                RegistryView.Registry64
            };

            foreach (var registryView in views)
            {
                var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, registryView);

                var key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes", true);

                if (key != null &&
                    new List<string>(key.GetSubKeyNames()).Contains(
                        @"ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        key.DeleteSubKeyTree(
                            @"ZetaProducer.SuperSlimScriptingEngineProfiler.SlimScriptEngineProfilerCallback", false);
                    }
                    catch (AccessViolationException)
                    {
                    }

                    key.Close();
                }

                key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\CLSID", true);

                if (key != null &&
                    new List<string>(key.GetSubKeyNames()).Contains($@"{{{ClsidString}}}"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        key.DeleteSubKeyTree($@"{{{ClsidString}}}", false);
                    }
                    catch (AccessViolationException)
                    {
                    }

                    key.Close();
                }

                key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(@"Environment", true);
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.DeleteValue(@"JS_PROFILER", false);
                    key.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private static RegistryKey checkCreateKey(RegistryView registryView, string keyPath)
        {
            // Achtung vor dem Wow6432Node-Schlüssel.
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039186/reading-the-registry-and-wow6432node-key

            var rs = new RegistrySecurity();

            // Jeder.
            var user = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);

            rs.AddAccessRule(
                new RegistryAccessRule(
                    user,
                    RegistryRights.FullControl,
                    InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                    PropagationFlags.None,
                    AccessControlType.Allow));

            var key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, registryView)
                .CreateSubKey(
                    keyPath,
                    RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree,
                    rs);

            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update July 2018**

I've once again got the initial error on my development machine when running directly from within Visual Studio 2017:

> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

After some try and error, I figured out that this was due to the fact, that I [configured my Visual Studio to always run as an administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12257110/107625).

When starting from within this context, somehow something seems to go wrong. I still don't know what exactly.

Solution for this was to simply start my executable directly from Windows File Explorer and not from within Visual Studio.

Another possible solution (which I didn't try) should be to not run Visual Studio as an administrator.