# Deleting Registry Key inprocserver32

Tags: c#, com, registry

I'm trying to clean up the registry from bits that my company's RTD/COM program has left in the registry. When I try to delete a registry subkey tree (using C#) the code usually works, however in some instances I get an error message "cannot delete a subkey tree because they subkey does not exist". I finally figured out that this is because I'm trying to delete a CLSID subkey, but since I'm on a 64bit machine the registry automatically reroutes me to the WOW6432NODE\CLSID directory. The problem is that the RTD/COM has in fact created the entries under the registry HKCR\CLSID\ and NOT HKCR\WOW6432NODE\CLSID\, so when I give the path of the actual registry I'm trying to delete the program is being rerouted to read the WOW6432NODE path, where it doesn't exist and therefore gives me the error. How am I supposed to delete this if I always get rerouted?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039186/reading-the-registry-and-wow6432node-key

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I actually saw that item and still couldn't figure it out. After looking at the comments there again, it turns out I needed to mark the build x86 AND have the registry pointing to Registry32 (which is not clear there).